# telethon and opentele conflict

Tags: python, telethon, telegram-api

I'm calling this in main.py:

```
from opentele.td import TDesktop
from opentele.tl import TelegramClient
from opentele.api import API, UseCurrentSession


async def save(name, path):
    client = TelegramClient(f"{name}.session")

    tdesk = await client.ToTDesktop(flag=UseCurrentSession)
    tdesk.SaveTData(path)
```

where I'm using TelegramClient from telethon, and I'm getting an error 'bytes or str expected, not <class 'int'>.' However, when I call it separately or in another file, there are no errors, and everything works

```
#main.py
 await client.start()
        await client(UpdateUsernameRequest(user_name))
        await save_tdata.save(user_name, f"{user_name}/tdata")
```

When I remove the line `await save_tdata.save(user_name, f"{user_name}/tdata")`, the error persists. However, the issue is resolved only when I remove `import save_tdata`. I want to emphasize that if I run it from other files, for example, create test.py and call `save_tdata.save()`, everything works fine.
I think it somehow conflicts with Telethon. I've tried giving them different names using 'as'.

Comment: Please, provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add full traceback.